# Rundeck behind and SSL Proxy

Tags: ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy, rundeck

I am currently trying to set up an environment with Rundeck running behind and nginx reverse ssl proxy. I found different tutorials online for this scenario but none of those worked for me. I am working in an linux environment where both rundeck and nginx run on. My nginx configuration file for rundeck loooks like this:

```
server {
        access_log   /var/log/nginx/rundeck.access.log  main;


        listen 443;
        listen       [::]:443;
        ssl    on;
        ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/conf.d/key.rsa;

        location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:4440/;
          proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
          proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Ssl on;
}

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

Furthermore I configured those parameters in rundeck: 
`framework.server.url = https://localhost:4440` and `grails.serverURL=https://lde71d6p.de.top.com:443`
I tried different combinations with https or only http, without port and with port. None of them works properly.

With the current configuration I get the following error situation.
If i try to call http://hostname.top.com -> Connection Error (seems fine because port 80 isn't handled by nginx)
https://hostname.top.com -> gets a 302 and is redirected to http://hostname.top.com/user/login;jsessionid=xxxxxxx and than gets an connection error.
https://hostname.top.com/user/login gets me straight to the login interface of rundeck. All fine.

Can anyone help me please to resolve the error situations I mentioned first?

Kind Regards,

Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind your error

Error-1: 
`listen 443` your server isn't listen on port 80, to fix it add `listen 80;` in your config.

Error-2: `location / {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:4440/;`
 which redirect requests to 4440, getting error code `302`.

Error-3 & 4: Wrong proxy config.

Please use below config to resolve your issue.

```
server {

listen 80;

server_name <hostname>;

location / {

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_redirect http://localhost:4440/ /;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:4440/;
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

To run Rundeck behind SSL proxy, you need the following three setting:

https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/wiki/FAQ#can-i-do-ssl-offloading

- Set up RunDeck as http
- in profile file, add option -Drundeck.jetty.connector.forwarded=true to RDECK_JVM
- Set framework.rundeck.url and grails.serverURL to use https

In your case, profile setting does not seem to have been done yet.

The profile is in `/etc/rundeck/profile`. (it may depend on the distribution)

Add options `-Drundeck.jetty.connector.forwarded=true` to `RDECK_JVM` as follows:

```
RDECK_JVM="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=$JAAS_CONF \
       -Dloginmodule.name=$LOGIN_MODULE \
       -Drdeck.config=$RDECK_CONFIG \
       -Drundeck.server.configDir=$RDECK_SERVER_CONFIG \
       -Dserver.datastore.path=$RDECK_SERVER_DATA/rundeck \
       -Drundeck.server.serverDir=$RDECK_INSTALL \
       -Drdeck.projects=$RDECK_PROJECTS \
       -Drdeck.runlogs=$RUNDECK_LOGDIR \
       -Drundeck.config.location=$RDECK_CONFIG/rundeck-config.properties \
       -Djava.io.tmpdir=$RUNDECK_TEMPDIR \
       -Drundeck.server.workDir=$RUNDECK_WORKDIR \
       -Dserver.http.port=$RDECK_HTTP_PORT \
       -Drundeck.jetty.connector.forwarded=true"
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, I forgot to mention this, I already changed the JVM arguments: `export RDECK_JVM="-Dloginmodule.conf.name=jaas-gdiscombined.conf \
    -Dloginmodule.name=combined -Drundeck.jetty.connector.forwarded=true"`This didnt help :(

Comment: In my `/etc/rundeck/framework.properties`, `framework.server.url` is http and `framework.rundeck.url` is https. Check your setting.